# Equilibrium of a system "a chain on a prism"

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Here is a sketch of a system

[image: a]

It is a homogeneous chain on a prism. It needs to find an equilibrium.

length of the chain is $l$

length of a horizontal part of the prism is $a$

angles of the prism are $\alpha$ and $\beta$

My thoughts are that we should take a length of a left part of the chain as a generalized coordinate, take potential energy, and find extrema of it. Using the Lagrange theorem we can find out an equilibrium.

But I am not sure how potential energy could look for such a system. I do not know how to treat such an object as a chain. In class, we are used to work with cubes, cylinders, triangles, etc. But not a chain. Can you help me?

Comment: There is a problem with a chain. It can bend sharply where one link meets another.  This introduces extra forces when it passes over a sharp corner. If that problem is ignored, your chain is not going to find an equilibrium.  But, you can place it in a position of unstable equilibrium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only generalized coordinate is the length of the homogeneous chain hanging at either side (say left side) or $x$.

Let's measure potential energy from the top of the prism as follows:
\begin{align*}
-V&=\int dmgy\sin\alpha+\int dmgy\sin\beta&(\because V<0\text{ for doing work towards gravity as the chain rests on the slant from the flat.})\\
-V&=\int_0^{x} \frac{mgy\sin\alpha}{l}dy+\int_0^{[l-(x+a)]} \frac{mgy\sin\beta}{l}dz\\
-V&=\frac{mg\sin\alpha}{2l}\left[y^2\right]_0^{x}+\frac{mg\sin\beta}{2l}\left[z^2\right]^{[l-(x+a)]}_0\\
-V&=\frac{mg\sin\alpha}{2l}x^2+\frac{mg\sin\beta}{2l}[l-(x+a)]^2\\
-V&=\frac{mg\sin\alpha}{2l}x^2+\frac{mg\sin\beta}{2l}(l^2+x^2+a^2+2xa-2xl-2al)\\
\end{align*}
Applying the Lagrange's equation,  where $L=T-V=-V$ for $T=0$ at equilibrium,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}&=0\\
-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial\dot{x}}\right)+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}&=0\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}&=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{mg\sin\alpha}{2l}x^2+\frac{mg\sin\beta}{2l}(l^2+x^2+a^2+2xa-2xl-2al)\right]&=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\sin\alpha(x^2)+\sin\beta(l^2+x^2+a^2+2xa-2xl-2al)\right]&=0\\
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}2x+2x+2a-2l&=0\\
x&=\frac{l-a}{1+\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! I very much appreciate your work!

Comment: @Sameer I think that $\sin(\beta) \mapsto — minus \sin(\beta)$ ?

Comment: @Eli $\sin\beta\rightarrow-\sin\beta\Rightarrow x\to+\infty$ as $\alpha\to\beta$. But we know by symmetry that $x=\frac{l-a}2$

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic statics problem. The tension along the upper surface must be constant and support the component of weight along each of the slanting surfaces.  T = λRg sin(β) = λLg sin(α) where λ is the mass/length and R and L are the lengths hanging on each side.